# Sitefinity multilingual site - Dynamic module related image showing (not translated) even after translating the content item

Tags: sitefinity

Sitefinity multilingual site - Dynamic module related image showing (not translated) even after translating the content item - issue

I am currently working on Sitefinity multilingual (English & Hindi) web application where I am getting a very strange issue regarding related media upload.

In my image gallery, I have a custom field for upload image. When I am adding a Hindi content for an image for the Hindi translation, the image is showing the (not translated) message and the image is not showing in the Hindi site after publish.

[image: thumb nail]

[image: My code]

Comment: Did you translate the image in Hindi at all?

Comment: no, I haven't translated any image.. here it is showing last published image irrespective of the language.. my question is how to mage image displayed respective of the language? can you please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using related media in a dynamic module on a multilingual site - you will need to have translated versions of that media available, in order for them to show on the translated version of that content type on the front end.

So if the item you're editing is for Hindi here, then your screenshot shows the second two images you have were created in English but don't have a Hindi version. You'll need to go into the image library, and translate that image.

As far as I can tell, you can't default to an image (or any kind of content) from another culture. This makes sense even for images though, because even if the images are the same, you should have different Alt text available for accessibility reasons.

What is nice though, is when you translate the image, you do not need to re-upload the image (unless you want to).